# 4367 bus error (core dumped) while doing git status

Tags: git

I'm getting a `[1]   4367 bus error (core dumped)` error when I did `git status`. I get a similar error while doing `git checkout` and `git rebase`.
Doing `git fsck --full` shows some dangling blobs.

`Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (151746/151746), done.
dangling blob 94529014d32888b9b52dcd3e3ebe0fa5246a673d
dangling blob 2d2d89f77670d5d1d04adfefb46fd8fba9952b31
dangling blob 2a58b248e38b523922a7cb005090366ff51cb9a5
dangling blob 0a4fa38cb8bd44fed054e5d3e5d0ebec0050c055
dangling blob 3f274cc0501b0f05c0cfa721d49a17ca0c7ffd7d
dangling blob 584396d133e29f785c18091c2348689b9e2ed7c8`